How to disable errors in node_modules/ for tsc?
I am not able to disable errors inside node_modules/.
Running tsc will give me the following errors:
Errors  Files
     8  node_modules/@rnmapbox/maps/src/components/Camera.tsx:450
     4  node_modules/@server/api-client/src/runtime.ts:28
     2  node_modules/react-native-paper/src/components/Typography/v2/StyledText.tsx:4
     1  node_modules/react-native-paper/src/components/Typography/v2/Text.tsx:9
     1  node_modules/react-native-paper/src/core/theming.tsx:4
     1  node_modules/react-native-paper/src/styles/themes/v2/DarkTheme.tsx:1
     1  node_modules/react-native-paper/src/styles/themes/v2/LightTheme.tsx:1
     1  node_modules/react-native-paper/src/styles/themes/v3/DarkTheme.tsx:1
     1  node_modules/react-native-paper/src/styles/themes/v3/LightTheme.tsx:1

This is a problem during CI/CD builds.
All my attempts to solve this did not resolve the problem. skipLibCheck or exclude didn't change the outcome of running tsc.
tsconfig.json
This is the current content of my tsconfig.json:
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "lib": [
      "esnext"
    ],
    "types": [
      "react-native",
      "jest",
      "node"
    ],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "paths": {
      "@firebase/auth": [
        "./node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/index.rn.d.ts"
      ]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "babel.config.js",
    "metro.config.js",
    "jest.config.js"
  ]
}


You can set includes to just your app folder to get around it.

@johnhaup I already tried this approach. I'd then get errors on basically anything. I assume that tsc simpyl requires node_modules in order to compile.
